# How to change the order of integration when angles and trigonometric functions are involved in limits?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

*Change the order of integration of*

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\cos(\theta)}\ \cos{(\theta)}\ dr\,d\theta$$

**Solution:**

First, I've made a plot of the given region:

$$0\leqslant\ r \leqslant \cos(\theta)$$

$$0\leqslant\ \theta \leqslant \pi/2$$

[image: Plot]

I have tried to define the new limits,

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\cos(\theta)}\ \cos(\theta)\ d\theta\, dr$$

Some suggestions, tips,... to understand how to define limits when angles and trigonometric functions are involved in the original limits?

Comment: Your picture isn't exactly correct.  In particular, the axes are wrong.  This should be a picture in the $r\theta$-plane, not in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: To get your head around the difference between the $r\theta$-plane and the $xy$-plane, [here's a plot of $r=r_0$ in both planes](http://i.imgur.com/1KaLZyU.jpg).  And [here's how you should have drawn your region](http://i.imgur.com/9CSjnIH.jpg).  It looks very similar to yours, but there's a big difference when it comes to the axes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get clear about your picture: the **horizontal** axis is the $\theta$-axis; that's where you need to put $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi/2$.  The vertical axis is the $r$-axis, the curve should only go as high as $r=1$, not as high as $\pi/2 \approx 1.57.$

For any fixed value of $\theta$, the value of $r$ goes from $0$ up to $\cos\theta$.  That's a vertical line segment in your picture.

For any fixed value of $r$, the value of $\theta$ goes from $0$ up to $\arccos r$.  That's a horizontal line in your picture.

So you get $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{\arccos r} \cos\theta \,d\theta \right) \,dr.$

Answer (score 0):

Your only mistake is using $\cos(\theta)$ in the bounds.

When we integrate with respect to $r$ first, the bounds are

$r=0$ and $r=\cos(\theta)$

However, when we integrate with respect to $\theta$ first, the bounds are

$\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \cos^{-1}(r)$ or $\theta = \arccos(r)$.